# Get all data in dictionary by using dictionary name

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need all data in a filled dictionary by using dictionary name below is my code

```
var data  = mAData.GetType().GetProperty("SEN").GetValue(mAData.SEN);
```

I do not know where i am missing please help.
my finding is the problem is in GetValue() parameter

Comment: Please show us the variable declaration for mAData and how you are populating it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you need reflection to use your dictionary?

Comment: i need all items in dictionary in concatenated form stored in a string

Comment: @Patrick tells the write thing that works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the value from the property `SEN`. That property belongs to `mAData`, not to `mAData.SEN`. You need to give the instance to which the property belongs:

```
var data  = mAData.GetType().GetProperty("SEN").GetValue(mAData);
```

I hope this code is just for testing purposes, since usually you can just call `mAData.SEN` (unless it is not accessible due to its protection level).

Comment: no its not for testing purpose, i am running a foreach loop on a list of dictionaries, and in replace of "SEN" i am using a dynamic value

Comment: So then this is testing code. You replace it with your actual values.

Comment: @Ralis don't spread information about your question all around, instead embed every useful piece in the question itself. If your SO question is made of 2 or more unrelated separate issues, ask them one at a time on separated SO questions.

Comment: @mjwills No, that is an entirely new question. As Massimiliano said: ask a new question.

Comment: under stood @MassimilianoKraus thank you guys let me ask a new question